# Update from one table to another table using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update data from one table to another table with year condition.

```
UPDATE pgptrans
SET dcamt1 = t2.ecamt1
FROM pgptrans t1 
INNER JOIN pgptrans060713 t2 ON t1.empcode = t2.empcode 
WHERE       
    t1.empcode LIKE '130%' 
    AND t1.yrmn = '201308' 
    AND t2.yrmn = '201207'
```

Here update `dcamt` of `pgptrans` table (to yr 201307) from `ecamt` of `pgptans060713` (from year should be 201308) with `empcode` starts from 130

please help me

thanx in advance

shubha

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.dcamt1 = t2.ecamt1
FROM pgptrans t1
INNER JOIN pgptrans060713 t2 ON t1.empcode = t2.empcode
WHERE t1.empcode LIKE '130%' 
    AND t1.yrmn = '201308' 
    AND t2.yrmn = '201207'
```

Comment: Perhaps, you would be interested to try our free on-line tool - http://www.sql-format.com/

Comment: @user1702346 if it like than than you have to check your where condtion.

Comment: @user1702346 your weoclome

Answer (score 0):

**To Update one table based on another table using INNER JOIN**

```
 UPDATE t1 SET 
        t1.status = 1
 FROM   table1 t1 
        INNER JOIN table t2 
                   ON t1.Id = t2.ID
 WHERE  t2.num = 15
```